# Why moving object from one smart pointer to another cause crash?

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers

I don't have much experience with smart pointers. I write simple state stack and I have problem with this function:

```
void StateStack::changeState(StatesType type)
{
    currentState = std::move(statesFactory(type));
}
```

This is the last pointer to the object, so smart pointer delete the object and I get crash.

State is a base class with virtual functions, MainMenu and LoadingScreen inherit from State.

```
 int main()
    {
        Application application;
        application.run();
    }


Application::Application()
    : window(sf::VideoMode(1024, 768), "Test", sf::Style::Close),
    stateStack(State::Context(window))//...
{
}


StateStack::StateStack(State::Context settedContext):
    context(settedContext)
{
    currentState = statesFactory(StatesType::GameLoading);
}

std::unique_ptr<State> StateStack::statesFactory(StatesType type)
{
    std::unique_ptr<State> state;

    if (type==StatesType::GameLoading)      //etc. TODO
    {
        state.reset(new GameLoadingState(std::shared_ptr<StateStack>(this), context));
    }
    else if (type == StatesType::MainMenu)
    {
        state.reset(new MainMenuState(std::shared_ptr<StateStack>(this), context));
    }

    return state;
}

void GameLoadingState::update(sf::Time dt)
{
    //...

    if (timeSinceStart.asSeconds() > 5)
    {
        stack->changeState(StatesType::MainMenu);
    }
}

    class State
    {
    public:
        State(std::shared_ptr<StateStack> parent, Context settedContext);
        virtual void handleEvent(const sf::Event& event) = 0;
        //virtual ~State();
    protected:
        std::shared_ptr<StateStack> stack;
    private:
        Context context;
    };
```

Initially State had virtual destructor and crashes occured there. I decided it's unnecessary and now move is the problem trigger.

Thank you in advance, I can send you more code if you point me what you need.

Comment: see http://sscce.org/

Comment: The rule here is to provide a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  That means removing anything unrelated to your problem (e.g. `draw`, `update`, `handleEvent`) and the shortest possible program that reproduces the issue, such that anyone can paste it into something like [an online IDE](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/).  So that means having a `main()` and everything, to show what your problem is.

Comment: `currentState = std::move(statesFactory(type));` can simply be `currentState = statesFactory(type);`...

Comment: @Jarod42 I know, but I tried this version when crash occured.

Comment: @HostileFork I'll change it

Comment: `std::shared_ptr<StateStack>(this)` is your error. `share_from_this` might be a solution, or a redesign should be made.

Comment: @Jarod42 could you explain it to me? If I use enable_shared_from_this and later shared_from_this() I will get bad weak_ptr exception. I would have to have at least one shared pointer pointing to StateStack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you construct a shared pointer from a raw pointer, that shared pointer will consider itself (and any copies made of it) to be the "ownership group" of the raw pointer, and responsible for its deletion.

So you don't want to construct a shared pointer from the same raw pointer more than once.  Here it appears you are constructing shared pointers from `this` multiple times.  Each such construction will consider itself an owner--so you'll get multiple deletes on the same pointer.

As @Jarod42 has pointed out, there is `enable_shared_from_this` which can be used to address the specific pattern of wanting to give out additional shared pointers to something that is already managed by a shared pointer:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this

> If I use enable_shared_from_this and later shared_from_this() I will get bad weak_ptr exception. I would have to have at least one shared pointer pointing to StateStack.

Yes.  See the examples in the link above.  If it feels "awkward" to get the shared pointers set up how you want, perhaps you should rethink the design.

If we put it in English, then what you have right now seems to be aiming for: *"When the last State in a StateStack goes away, the StateStack will automatically be destroyed."*  Is that reasonable/necessary?

How many `StateStack`s are there in your program?  In terms of lifetime management, could you just make it so you are sure that the stacks outlive the states?  Then you could just use ordinary references to point from the states to the stacks, and destroy the stacks after you were sure the states weren't being used.

If you're used to programming in garbage-collected languages, you may tend to try and overuse `shared_ptr`.  Consider a more hierarchical way of thinking about ownership where possible.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I have been thinking about smart pointers and I concluded that earlier I stupidly assumed newly created shared pointers somehow communicate. I've read some articles and that's clear for me now.